# Private Git repo - freezes at pulling

Tags: linux, git, ssh, compression, debian

I just setup git on my linux server and configured SSH - I want to create private repository to work with my friends. When I'm pulling or cloning that repo everything works fine (LAN), but when my friend tries pull or clone it (over Internet),
git hangs at:

```
remote: Compressing objects: x
```

where x is always lower than 17%.

**What's wrong with it or how could I fix it?**

PS: I not using gitosis, I initialized that remote repo with: `git --bare init`.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

The results commands:

```
$ cat .git/config

[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://git@server:port/~/repo_name.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

```
$ git fetch -v
Enter passphare for key '/c/Users/dev/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 76, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 21% (12/55)
```

However, when my friend got ZIP with sources and he pushed it, everything worked fine.
So he is able to push. I added an empty file and pushed it, he successfully downloaded (pulled) it.

Comment: Does it help when you exec `git gc` on the server-repo? Also are there different protocols (ssh/git/static-http/"intelligent"-http) involved? And do you use the same user-account for both your and your friends access, or are they different (I'm thinking about permission problems)?

Comment: @Rudi Well, when I executed `git gc` throught SSH locally (server is running on my computer) it completed, but when my friend tried to do the same thing it freezed (cursor is flashing for ever). He tried to pull after that and it freezed at `Compressing objects: 7%`.
Yes, we have one account for git, and we are using SSH protocol (origin looks like this, on both computers): `ssh://git@server_uri:port/~/repo_name.git`. Git repo is in home directory of git account. By the way, we are using `git pull origin master`.

Comment: it sounds like that there is a network component which drops the ssh connection after a few seconds, very likely a defect NAT. You can try with wireshark on both ends if there are TCP packets of the connection are dropped after a certain amount of time (I suspect missing ACK packets server->client).

Comment: Just in case it could help, can your friend try a `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`before cloning?

Comment: @Vonc Unfortunately it doesn't helps. It does still freezes at `10`-`14%`

Answer (score 7):

Get your friend to try:

```
git fetch -v
```

If that doesn't give you the answer then get him to do this:

```
cat .git/config
```

If your server is secure then update your question to include the output of that command. If it's not secure then change the IP and other identifying details to a fake IP and fake details, but try not to alter anything else as you may end up providing misleading info.

---

Edit based on update:

The url should start with "ssh://" not "ssh/". Although I'm about to go double check that.

Comment: Sorry, it's `ssh://`. I just copied it with some emoticon and it's missing.

Comment: Damn, well then I really don't know as everything else looks normal. Is it possible for your friend to come over to your house? Either that or for you to try cloning/pulling your your repo from outside of your network. That way you can figure out if the problem is on his or your end.

Answer (score 3):

If Git push/pull freeze using a config that previously worked, try restarting the computer.

It sounds strange yet I have experienced this on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Exactly this just happened for me (on Mac OS). Not sure what service exactly needed to be reset, but you're onto something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I went into my Ethernet adapter settings and changed the Jumbo Packet size from 1514 bytes to 9014 bytes.

Comment: It's sort of hard to believe that jumbo packets are required for git to work.

Comment: I think it may actually be another setting that in combination with the smaller size it failed.  I've been having issues with my network card for months.  It's probably a driver issue.